# Function not defined even it is (html+JS)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I made tabs that open up when clicked, CSS makes the links look like they are tabs. It used to function at some point but then it stopped and I have no idea if there is a typo somewhere, am i missing something, or did i break it by adding the last functions (the Load() onwards, trying to access xml and load up the stats into html textfields using the name, but it is incomplete still.)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
function openRPG(evt, rpgName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(rpgName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

function load(){
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var idname = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       document.getElementById("").innerHTML = this.t
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  LoadXML(this, idname);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "helper_database.xml", true);
xhttp.send();
}
function LoadXML(xml, name){
var x, i, xmlDoc, nametxt, areEqual;
xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
nametxt = name;
if (areEqual = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name").toUpperCase() === nametxt.toUpperCase(); //vertailu oikeasti, tähän kohtaan, ks. kommenttirivi 52.
for (i = 0; i< x.length; i++) {
 if (areEqual = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name").toUpperCase() === nametxt.toUpperCase())
 {
  document.getElementById("ComFocus").innerHTML = nametxt;
 }
}
}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="helper_styles.css">
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<title>Roleplay Helper</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>A roleplay helper</h1>
<ul class="tab">
<li><a class="tablinks" id="da" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openRPG(event, 'DragonAgeRPG')">DragonAgeRPG</a></li>
<li><a class="tablinks" id="dh" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openRPG(event, 'DarkHeresy')">DarkHeresy</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="DragonAgeRPG" class="tabcontent">
<p>Dragon age is a dark fantasy roleplaying game, which uses 3d6 system. Main features include ease of use and stunt point system.</p>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Start by filling out the form, or fill out the name and click 'Load'. Afterwards you can click 'Save' and it is saved onto the database for later use.">Hover over for instructions!<br></a>
Name:<input type="text" class="name" /> <button type="button" text="Save" class="button">Save</button> <button text="Save" class="button" onclick="load()">Load</button>
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Ability</th>
  <th>Bonus/Penalty<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add the bonus or penalty of your relevant ability.">?</a></th>
  <th>Focuses<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="List all the focuses you have in a row, separated by space."><p class="helptip">?</p></a></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Communication</td>
  <td><input type="text" class="stat" id="ComBonus"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="stat" id="ComFocus"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Constitution</td>
  <td><input type="text" class="stat" id="ConBonus"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="stat" id="ConFocus"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Cunning</td>
  <td><input type="text" class="stat" id="ComBonus"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="stat" id="ComFocus"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Dexterity</td>
  <td><input type="text" class="stat" id="ComBonus"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="stat" id="ComFocus"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Magic</td>
  <td><input type="text" class="stat" id="ComBonus"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="stat" id="ComFocus"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Perception</td>
  <td><input type="text" class="stat" id="ComBonus"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="stat" id="ComFocus"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Strength</td>
  <td><input type="text" class="stat" id="ComBonus"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="stat" id="ComFocus"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Willpower</td>
  <td><input type="text" class="stat" id="ComBonus"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="stat" id="ComFocus"/></td>

 </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="DarkHeresy" class="tabcontent">
<p>Synkkä ja myrskyinen 40k Peli</p>
<input type="text" class="name" />
</div>


<script src="helper_javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
function openRPG(evt, rpgName) {
// Declare all variables
var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

// Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}

// Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}

// Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
document.getElementById(rpgName).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
```

}

Comment: There is a syntax error `if (areEqual = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name").toUpperCase() === nametxt.toUpperCase();` should probably be `if (areEqual = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name").toUpperCase() === nametxt.toUpperCase()){`

Comment: If  I click run snippet I get a JS error. I'm guessing the console had something similar. You should keep an eye out for these things.

Comment: I knew it was something on the "coding blindness". I much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incomplete "if" statement in your loadXML function.
Check this line

```
if (areEqual = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name").toUpperCase() === nametxt.toUpperCase(); //vertailu oikeasti, tähän kohtaan, ks. kommenttirivi 52.
```

You have missed ")" and it is not clear where the "if" statement ends.

Comment: I knew it was something on the "coding blindness". I much appreciate it. my fault is much in the reason that I get easily distracted by other parts of the code and I forget to complete the syntax.